# ExtJS 4.2.1 in Mobile Browsers

Tags: extjs, mobile

Can the applications developed for desktop browsers using ExtJS 4.2.1 will work fine in the mobile/touch devices with out any resolution issues. Please suggest do we need to do any changes for running the application in mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Extjs 4 and below is not optimised for use on mobile devices, so I doubt this is much you can do to overcome your resolution issues.

Extjs 5 is targeted for both desktop and high end tablet devices such as iPad and Galaxy Tab.

Sencha Touch offers the best support for the most number of mobile devices whilst still working on HTML5 supported desktop browsers.

Note - they have announced they are merging ExtJs and Touch. More details to follow at their upcoming SenchaCon event.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS 4 can work OK on tablet devices. 
For mobile browsers or hybrid mobile apps consider work in Sencha Touch.